# Send Server Response in bulks in express app

Tags: node.js, oracle, express

I am using the oracledb driver for my app combined with this library https://github.com/sagiegurari/simple-oracledb

I wish to send the results from my query in bulks, but I keep getting the error:

> Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

Here is my code:

```
router.get('/', function (req,res) {
"use strict"; 

oracledb.getConnection(connAttrs.database, function (err, connection) {
    if (err) {
        // Error connecting to DB
        res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.status(500).send(JSON.stringify({
            status: 500,
            message: "Error connecting to DB",
            detailed_message: err.message
        }));
        return;
    }
    connection.query("Select * from solvedtasks",{},{
        splitResults: true, //True to enable to split the results into bulks, each bulk will invoke the provided callback (last callback invocation will have empty results)
        bulkRowsAmount: 1000 //The amount of rows to fetch (for splitting results, that is the max rows that the callback will get for each callback invocation)
    },
        function onResults (err, results) {
            if (err) {
                res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                res.status(500).send(JSON.stringify({
                    status: 500,
                    message: "Error getting the user profile",
                    detailed_message: err.message
                }));
            } else if(results.length)
            {
                res.send(results);
            }
            else {
                // Release the connection
                console.log("done");
                connection.release(
                    function (err) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.error(err.message);
                        } else {
                            console.log("GET /SolvedTasks : Connection released");
                        }
                    });
            }
        });
});
});
```

This error obviously happens because it keeps doing res.send(results) more than once. I get just the first 1000 rows and after that the error occurs. Any idea how to solve this, keep sending the results in bulks but not getting the error?